# How to get first element of array inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that looks like this

```
const array_eps = {
            episode3: ["https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/kzZ6KXDM1RI","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/T8y_RsF4TSw","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c"],
            episode2: ["https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c"],
            episode1: ["https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c"],
    };
```

What i want to do here is get the first element of array that act as value in a object.

I'm already do something like this

```
array_eps[Object.keys(array_eps)[0]]
```

But it's return the whole array not only the first element.

Thankyou

Comment: `array_eps["episode3"][0];` Why are you using `Object.keys` here?

Comment: `array_eps[Object.keys(array_eps)[0]][0]`

Comment: @HR01M8055 oh yeah i feel so dumb for asking this, thankyou!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array_eps = {
            episode3: ["https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/kzZ6KXDM1RI","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/T8y_RsF4TSw","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c"],
            episode2: ["https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c"],
            episode1: ["https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/qrtKLNTB71c"],
    };
    
console.log(array_eps[Object.keys(array_eps)[0]][0]);
```